# Very strange behavior of operator 'is' with methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, python-internals

Why is the first result `False`, should it not be `True`?

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict.__repr__ is OrderedDict.__repr__
False
>>> dict.__repr__ is dict.__repr__
True
```

Comment: Python 3.3 returns True

Comment: @JustinEngel: That's because Python 3 does away with unbound methods, all methods are bound. Try `OrderedDict().__repr__ is OrderedDict().__repr__` in Python 3 and you'll see the same behaviour.

Comment: I curious how something like this would ever be touched on in practical code

Comment: @NickT: Verifying a monkey-patched method would require knowledge of how methods are bound. Adding a method from one class to another class would also require that you extract the function object, not the method, etc.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For user-defined functions, in Python 2 *unbound* and *bound* methods are created on demand, through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html); `OrderedDict.__repr__` is such a method object, as the wrapped function is implemented as a [pure-Python function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e28004fb30c0/Lib/collections.py#l164).

The descriptor protocol will call the [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) on objects that support it, so `__repr__.__get__()` is called whenever you try to access `OrderedDict.__repr__`; for classes `None` (no instance) and the class object itself are passed in. Because you get a *new* method object each time the function `__get__` method is invoked, `is` fails. It is not the same method object.

`dict.__repr__` is not a custom Python function but a C function, and its `__get__` descriptor method [essentially just returns `self` when accessed on the class](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e28004fb30c0/Objects/descrobject.c#l59). Accessing the attribute gives you the same object each time, so `is` works:

```
>>> dict.__repr__.__get__(None, dict) is dict.__repr__  # None means no instance
True
```

Methods have a `__func__` attribute referencing the wrapped function, use that to test for identity:

```
>>> OrderedDict.__repr__
<unbound method OrderedDict.__repr__>
>>> OrderedDict.__repr__.__func__
<function __repr__ at 0x102c2f1b8>
>>> OrderedDict.__repr__.__func__.__get__(None, OrderedDict)
<unbound method OrderedDict.__repr__>
>>> OrderedDict.__repr__.__func__ is OrderedDict.__repr__.__func__
True
```

Python 3 does away with *unbound* methods, `function.__get__(None, classobj)` returns the function object itself (so it behaves like `dict.__repr__` does). But you will see the same behaviour with *bound* methods, methods retrieved from an instance.

Comment: As a simply test to prove this for yourself, create a class with its ``__repr__`` method as ``__repr__ = lambda :x``, and the ``is`` test will fail. Actually, overriding ``__repr__`` in general will cause ``is`` to fail.

Comment: And, in the general case, NO classes' pure-python unbound methods compare as ``True`` with ``is``.

Comment: @aruisdante: well, you can create (more than one) reference to the method object, and then you can still use `is`. But retrieving a method from a class gives you a fresh object because the function `__get__` method produces a new object.

Comment: Ah yeah, sure, I meant via direct comparison as the OP did. And obviously your answer actually says that, it just isn't immediately obvious. Perhaps providing a simple example where you show that for ANY class with ANY pure-python methods this will happen would be helpful to future viewers of this question.

Comment: @aruisdante: I am more focusing on the difference here with `dict.__repr__`; talking *just* about the method objects is a duplicate, actually.

Answer (score 1):

The two `OrderedDict.__repr__` are not bound to the same object. If you try:

```
 OrderedDict.__repr__ == OrderedDict.__repr__
```

you'll see that they have the same value.